# Windows 8 hang after installing virtualbox

Tags: windows-8, virtualbox

After I install virtualbox, my pc hang at reboot.

After sometime, it prompted me more setting, I choose to restore to a certain point, but it fail to restore because of antivirus.

How to disable antivirus. I am worried my data and installed software is lost.

How can I solve the problem. It take hours to see the restore mode.

Comment: Try using windows 8 repair disc.........

Comment: Any luck booting into safe mode?

Answer (score 0):

reinstall in incompatibility mode for earlier version of windows.
right click on setup -> open properties -> click on compatibility tab -> Tick Run this program in compatibility mode for -> select windows 7 or earlier version on which it your application worked successfully.

```
            -->> apply -->> Ok
```

run the setup to install again.